# Import contacts from different social networking sites and invite to my drupal site

Tags: users, emails, social-network

I am in the process of building a social networking site.I need to allow my users to be able to invite their friends as well on to the site. Using the Invite module alone will not cater to my need. What i need is this to work with some other module. I want users to be able to import their contacts from Facebook, Twitter, Gmail and then select between the contacts the users to invite. I thought of using the Contact Importer module but it has issues with social networking platforms. Please advice. You may have a look at the following image to understand my use case. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQCmA.jpg

Comment: This might help you http://openinviter.com/. Its free and open source

Comment: Also, i am using the OpenInviter engine

Comment: I am using that... it says that it does support social networking sites.  http://drupal.org/node/654638

Comment: There are individual plug ins available from OpenInviter but how do i integrate them with Drupal...especially as the use case/design which i have...http://i.imgur.com/BAczhzX.jpg?1

Comment: how do i integrate facebook etc for this

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [invite](http://drupal.org/project/invite) along with the [Contact Importer](http://drupal.org/project/contact_importer)

**Invite**

> Invitations are important to create network effects and exponential
>   growth of a community of interest. This module provides an Invite a
>   friend feature to allow your users to send and track invitations to
>   join your site.

**Contact Importer**

> Contact Importer provides a form for your users to enter their email
>   address and password. The contacts from their address book are then
>   retrieved.
>
> Contact Importer can be used with any Drupal form. No codding
>   necessary. It can be used with an invite module, a user import module,
>   an emailing module, or anything else that you can think of.
>
> The current release interfaces with the Octazen or [Open Inviter](http://openinviter.com/)
>   retrieval services. But the architecture is modular and can be very
>   easily extended to use other retrieval services such as [Contact Mines](http://www.contactmines.com/),
>   [ImproSys](http://www.improsys.com/importer.htm), or [IpInvite](http://www.iplussoft.com/product/iplusinvite).

Comment: thanks...but i am already using the Invite module and Open Inviter engine for the Contact Importer module.The issue lies in integrating them with social networking sites...